# in javascript, How do I extract data from xml in such format?

Tags: javascript, xml

I understand when the format is in such

```
<MyML>
  <test1>47.2727</test1>
  <test2>54.3421</test2>
</MyML>
```

I can use

```
 $(xmldata).find('MyML').each(function(){
 var currV = $(this).find('test1').text();
 var dateT =   ($(this).find('test2').text();
```

to get those two values.

But what if the xml format become this?

```
<MyML>
<test1 val="47.2727"/>
<test2 val="54.3421"/>
</MyML>
```

and attribute could me more than just two, perhaps test3, test4 or more
what command should i use to get all values?

Comment: that's `Javascript`, not `PHP`. Do you want it in PHP? Or should it be retagged?

Comment: sorry its in Javascript, my mistakes

Comment: You should take off the PHP tag, too, since it's not dealing with it here.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(this).find('test1').attr('val');
```

etc...